# How to combine docker and sklearn

Tags: docker, scikit-learn

I am trying to to convert a trained scikit-learn classifier into a Docker container.
I found the [sklearn2docker](https://github.com/KhaledSharif/sklearn2docker) project on github, but it failed.

I generate the `test.py` script from the following code:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
iris = load_iris()
input_df = DataFrame(data=iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
clf.fit(input_df.values, iris['target'])

from sklearn2docker.constructor import Sklearn2Docker

s2d = Sklearn2Docker(
    classifier=clf,
    feature_names=iris['feature_names'],
    class_names=iris['target_names'].tolist()
)
s2d.save(name="classifier", tag="iris")
```

`python test.py` runs the script and generates a container.

An error occurrs when I used the following code to predict:

```py
from os import system
system("docker run -d -p 5000:5000 classifier:iris && sleep 5")

from requests import post
from pandas import read_json
request = post("http://localhost:5000/predict_proba/split", 
    json=input_df.to_json(orient="split"))
result = read_json(request.content.decode(), orient="split")
print(result.head())
```

The error is as follows:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict/split (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]  Connection refused',))

I also try to directly use the `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt` from `constructor.py` in the sklearn2docker directory to generate the container using `app.py` in the `sklearn2docker` directory, but wasn't successful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmNLa.png)

Comment: What do you mean by turning it into a docker container? You can always get a container with Python, add sklearn, add the pickled file, and that's a model available in a container.

Comment: use `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 classifier:iris` in your command prompt or poweshell and then run the command `docker ps` and show the results

Comment: Does the container actually start?  Are you running your script with `sudo` or something else that has the appropriate system-level permission to launch a container?  One of your first debugging steps here should be to remote the `docker run -d` option and make sure it's actually coming up successfully.

Comment: I use the ubuntu18.04 installed docker,When test.py is executed, the container has been successfully created.I took a picture of it up here.When I run the command:docker run -d -p 5000:5000 classifier:iris,I use docker container ls,You see that the container is not started, but when I delete the image, it prompts me that the image is being used by the container